# dyld: Library not loaded: Reason: image not found

Tags: ios, frameworks

I know there is plenty of topics on this issue, to be honest, I think I have read all of them in the past 3 days, but none of them help me to solve my issue.

I have to build an iOS app implementing a custom framework, build by my own.

When I want to run my app on a real device, here is what I get (XXX is replaced for confidentiality of course) :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0FCB15D6-B961-47A6-96A1-2CA896634277/XXX.app/Frameworks/XXX.framework/XXX
  Reason: image not found
```

Following all topics, I tried to put the framework in the embedded binaries and stuff, but nothing worked...

[image: Embedded libraries]

[image: Embedded frameworks]

If someone has another idea...I'll take it !

Comment: Did you added your framework to embedded Binaries ?

Comment: yes (first screenshot)

Comment: Any updates? I'm running into the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

The framework was build with an older version of xCode (8.2), so I downgraded my project in xCode 8.2, and the issue vanished...not sure this is the best way to resolve it, but it works.